# How to use multiple HTML select tags make an SQL query

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to do is create a form where the user selects an option from 2 'select' tags and then the value from the select tags is used for an SQL query (i.e `results.php?select=option1+option2`). I've already managed to make it so that one of the values is used in the query, however I can't get it so that both values are used in the query.

This is my code so far:

```
$input = $_GET['input']; //this is for the text input - ignore
$topic = $_GET['topic']; // the first select box value which works well
$location = $_GET['location']; //the second select box value which isnt being inserted into the query
$combined = $input . $topic . $location;
$terms = explode(" ", $combined);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
```

Comment: You're concatenating your input variables but then exploding the result on `space`. It's likely that there will be no space between the end of one input and the beginning of the next. Note also that your code is susceptible to SQL Injection.

Comment: You should put spaces between `$input`, `$topic` and `$location` like this: `$combined = $input . ' ' . $topic . ' ' . $location;` in order to explode them correctly: `$terms = explode(" ", $combined);`

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

Why are you combining the terms then splitting them again? :/. There's no need to. You are also separating strings using a " " but if there is no spacing between the text the array will take both values as one

```
$input = $_GET['input']; //this is for the text input - ignore
$topic = $_GET['topic']; // the first select box value which works well
$location = $_GET['location'];
$terms[]=$input;
$terms[]=$topic;
$terms[]=$location;

$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each){
    if ($each != $terms[count($terms)-1]) //If $each is not the last item in the array
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
```